# Regex with dynamic digits number is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will work as the following pattern:

*tariff_0* - `false`; *tariff* - `false`

*tariff_0_0* - `true`; *tariff_100_50* - `true`

I've read that we can trigger digits with `[0-9]+` expression, but unfortunately, it is not working in my case.

Here is a link to my RegEx: [RegEx](http://regexr.com/4jn3p)

And my Regex: `/tariff_[0-9]+_[0-9]+/`

Comment: You should enable the global flag at the right top. See https://regexr.com/4jn4k

Comment: can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No need to post an answer, your pattern works :) The only thing missing was that the global flag was not enabled on regexr.com.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the current regular expression is that it stops finding matches at the first encounter.

Using the `global` flag would find as many matches as there are.

**ex :**

```
/tariff_[0-9]+_[0-9]+/g
```

Here, `g` is the global flag

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern: `/^tariff(_[0-9]){2,}$/`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str1 = 'tariff_0';
var str2 = 'tariff';
var str3 = 'tariff_0_0';
var str4 = 'tariff_100_50';
var str5 = 'tariff_100_500';
var patt = new RegExp("tariff_([0-9])+_([0-9])");
console.log(patt.test(str1));
console.log(patt.test(str2));
console.log(patt.test(str3));
console.log(patt.test(str4));
console.log(patt.test(str5));
```

Note:- This Regex will first check string contains `_` >>> number is between [0-9] >>> the same process as above...